# Реализация клиент-серверного приложения

Tags: c#, asp.net, сокет, wcf, клиент-сервер

Имеется следующая архитектура: клиентская часть(dll-ка на C#) отсылает определенное количество картинок на сервер(либо Windows Service, либо Web Service), где они обрабатываются, а потом отсылается ответ в виде XML файла результатов обработки.

Клиент - это просто автоматизированное приложение, без интерфейса и ввода вывода.

Сервер. На нем крутится движок, использующий многопоточность (с помощью *ThreadPool*) для обработки картинок.
Соответственно, когда обращается новый клиент, сервер создает новый поток, в котором происходит обработка, по окончанию он отсылает ответ пользователю(xml-файл).
Нагрузка на сервер планируется не очень большая 3-20 одновременных подключений.

Пока что я не могу понять какая архитектура взаимодействия лучше всего подойдет для моего случая. Есть несколько путей реализации, либо писать асинхронный сервер на сокетах, либо использовать *WCF*, или просто написать *ASP.NET* приложение и залить его на *IIS*(к этому варианту я склоняюсь больше всего).

Какой протокол передачи лучше всего использовать? Хватит ли *HTTP* для передачи большого количества картинок(тогда можно двигаться в направлении Web Service), или стоит задуматься о *TCP/IP*(здесь уже WCF)?

Кому интересно, несколько статей по созданию клиент-серверного приложения:

[Example with ASYNC/AWAIT](http://bsmadhu.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/simplify-asynchronous-programming-with-c-5-asyncawait/)

[Example with THREADS](http://mikeadev.net/2012/07/multi-threaded-tcp-server-in-csharp/)

[Example with SOCKETS](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5306/tcp-socket-server)

Comment: А клиент на каком языке? Если на C#, то, по-моему, удобней всего использовать WCF - с ним легко работать и есть все функции.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP, WCF и голый TCP справляются с заливкой картинок примерно одинаково.

Особенно если учесть, что HTTP работает поверх TCP, а WCF - или поверх HTTP, или с собственным протоколом поверх TCP, в зависимости от настроек биндинга.

Никакой *ощутимой* разницы между реализациями с точки зрения производительности не будет.

То же самое с типом хостинга - между Self-Hosted и IIS нет практически никакой разницы (не при вашей нагрузке).

Вам стоит использовать то, что вам удобнее в написании и поддержке.

Comment: Окей, спасибо за овтет!

Comment: Еще у меня такой вопрос: если напишу Self-Hosed приложение для серверной части, работающей с помощью ASYNC/AWAIT подхода, какие у меня могут возникнуть сложности с развертыванием на серверных машинах под управлением Windows Server. Я так понимаю в данном случае должна крутиться какая-то служба или сервис, а также фаерволл не должен блокировать мои соединения.

Comment: @АлексейСеров да, вам придется использовать сервис, но его достаточно легко создать и поставить (впрочем, вебсайт - проще). С firewall - вам придется открывать порт. Как и в случае с сайтом (просто 80-й порт открыт по умолчанию).