# Протокол общения клиент-серверного приложения

Tags: c#, .net, json, tcp

Пишу приложения клиент-серверного типа. Передаваться будут текстовые данные через интернет, скорость и стабильность которого оставляет желать лучшего.
Клиент берет данные с файла, добавляет к ним свой ID, далее всё это в формат Json со сжатием Gzip и отправляет с помощью TCPClient+StreamWriter.
Сервер получает исходные данные с помощью TCPListner+StreamReader и записывает в БД.

Общение между приложениями идут по протоколу TCP.

Теперь вопросы: клиент отправляет серверу данные и ждёт подтверждения, чтобы отправить следующие. Вот как правильно сервер должен ответить? Байтом, служебными командами какими-то или может есть готовое решение для этого? Просто неохота велосипед изобретать.
И второй вопрос: концепция приложения в целом верна? Может я переборщил с технологиями(json, gzip) и не стоило так усложнять.

P.S. Данные отправляются ежесекундно, размер примерно 1400 байт. На начальных этапах будет не больше 10 клиентов.

Comment: Не претендую на ответ, но если мне не изменяет память, то протокол TCP сам по себе подразумевает гарантию доставки пакетов, в отличие, например, от UDP: **TCP: протокол ориентирован на работу с подключениями и передает данные в виде потоков байтов. .... TCP - "надежный" протокол, потому что в нем используются контрольные суммы для проверки целостности данных и отправка подтверждений, чтобы гарантировать, что переданные данные приняты без искажений.** [(1)](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/tcpip.php). Потому можно и не отправлять, думаю, клиенту подтверждение.

Comment: Сервер должен отвечат так, что бы клиент понял. Лично я бы в каждое сообщение добавлял бы номерок и сервер отвечал назад с указанием этого номера. При коннекте Клиент запрашивает последний полученный номер у сервера - это решит проблему потерянного пакета. Но у этой схемы есть один недостаток - оно медленно. Поэтому, посылки и подтверждения должны быть ассинхронны.

в целом, я бы взял какой-нибудь mq (http://zeromq.org/ к примеру) и сделал все на нем. Это решит много проблем.

Comment: Еще [тут вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454215/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?rq=1) был близкий по тематике вопрос.

Comment: @KoVadim, а это мысль. В данных у меня есть дата, вот её можно отправлять и её же использовать для поиска последних отправленных данных. MQ рассматривал, но что-то я не до конца понимаю суть её работы, точнее, не вижу шаги, которые она делает, из-за этого какое-то не доверие. Плюс ко всему настройку ПК надо проводить(в случае с MSMQ), а для обычного пользователя это сложно.

Comment: @BlackWitcher по поводу надежности TCP я не сомневаюсь, синхронность мне нужна для того чтобы я мог оперативно отловить разрыв соединения и знать на каком именно месте этот сбой произошел.

Comment: >  В данных у меня есть дата

Не нужно надеятся на дату. Она может сильно менятся. 

> синхронность мне нужна для того чтобы я мог оперативно отловить разрыв соединения < если есть номерки, то сервер всегда может сообщить свой последний номер.

Comment: @KoVadim, в файле строки вида: время_сбора_данных;номер;значение;номер;значение... Новая строка начинается опять со времени. Следовательно время сбора данных можно брать как идентификатор строки. Номера строки, как такового нет, его придётся присваивать. Процедура не сложная, но опять же, некоторое время нужно.

Comment: время берется локальное? тогда у Вас будут проблемы один раз год гарантированно:)

Comment: @KoVadim, да, локальное. Данные из файла, привязаны ко времени. Что за проблемы?

Comment: В некоторых странах переводят время. И один раз в год один час повторяется. Но вроде в России это дело отменили. Но есть ещё одно - нет никакой гарантии, что кто то не "поправит часы", даже сама винда время от времени корректирует.

Comment: @KoVadim, заставили Вы подумать над ключевыми полями. =) Номер мне не подходит потому что файлов может быть несколько, следовательно, у каждого файла нумерация будет идти заново, а в БД она будет общая для всех файлов. Можно конечно открывать каждый файл, считать их, но это трудозатратно, файлы могут быть >1гб. Если будут проблемы с повторяющимся временем, время внезапно станет меньше, впринципе, мне не важно, буду отправлять как есть. Клиент должен сам следить за правильностью даты, ну или не трогать её во время работы программ.

Comment: Вот здесь писал про обмен по Tcp/IP https://habrahabr.ru/post/311128/  и здесь  http://infostart.ru/public/525806/

Comment: Так чем вас ZeroMQ не устроила? Не надо сравнивать с MSMQ, там совершенно другой подход.

Comment: Если же хочется высокоуровневого протокола - посмотрите на WCF.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ZeroMQ хороша, не стал её применять, т.к. небольшая реализация передачи данных уже готова и на первых парах она пойдёт. А вообще чуть позже попробую с ней сделать, уж больно хорошие отзывы о ней в сети.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, сделал реализацию на ZeroMQ. Компактно, красиво и главное работает. Осталось только разобраться с ZSocketType, не подскажите какой лучше выбрать в моём случае? Сейчас у клиента поставил REQ, на сервере REP.

Comment: @Николай вот видите, сами разобрались...

Answer (score 1):

Порт вы можете указать в префиксе _listener, знак "+" означает что будут слушаться все Ip адреса(можно указать конкретный). Добавляя функции типа "ListenerCallback" вы можете запускать несколько прослушивателей(добавляя нужный делегат в метод BeginGetContext) на разных портах и для каждого делать свой обработчик. Выберет порты типа 30XXX и никому вы мешать "скорее всего" не будите. Асинхронность реализована под старый .Net, без использования async await; Вы говорили что нужно сжимать данные. В примере используется библиотека Ionic.Zip.dll(https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). В дополнение к этому все же советую ознакомиться с https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx;

```
public class Server
{
    private delegate void AsyncResponse(HttpListenerContext context, ParseRequest parse);
    private HttpListener _listener;

    public bool Start()
    {
        int port = 31234;
        string prefixMain = String.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", "+", port.ToString());
        try
        {
            _listener = new HttpListener();
            _listener.Prefixes.Add(prefixMain);
            _listener.Start();
            _listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, _listener);
            Console.Write("Запущен прослушиватель запросов по адресу " + prefixMain);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Невозможно запустить прослушиватель запросов по адресу " + prefixMain + "; Ошибка :" + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener = null;
            Console.Write(" Сервер успешно остановлен ");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.Write(" Не удалось остановить сервер");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void CallbackDelegate(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        AsyncResponse getAsyncresponse = (AsyncResponse)result.AsyncState;
        getAsyncresponse.EndInvoke(result);
    }

    private void ListenerCallbackTestAsync(IAsyncResult result, ParseRequest parse, CallBackFunction callBack)
    {

        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
        if (!listener.IsListening)
            return;

        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        WaitCallback waite = new System.Threading.WaitCallback(GetAsyncResponse);
        WaitCallbacObject waiteCallbackObject = new WaitCallbacObject() { Context = context, Parse = parse };
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waite, waiteCallbackObject);

        result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(callBack), listener);
    }

    private void GetAsyncResponse(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            WaitCallbacObject waitCallbackObject = state as WaitCallbacObject;
            HttpListenerRequest request = waitCallbackObject.Context.Request;
            StreamReader input = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);
            var inputText = input.ReadToEnd();
            string responseString = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                responseString = waitCallbackObject.Parse(inputText);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responseString = ex.ToString();
            }

            HttpListenerResponse response = waitCallbackObject.Context.Response;
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
            Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            response.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            byte[] pr = ZipByte(buffer);
            response.ContentLength64 = pr.Length;
            output.Write(pr, 0, pr.Length);
            output.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Ошибка при обработке запроса: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ParseRequest parse = ExecuteControllerMethod;
        CallBackFunction callback = ListenerCallback;
        ListenerCallbackTestAsync(result, parse, callback);
    }


    public string ExecuteControllerMethod(string inputText)
    {
        // Здесь можете добавить  обработку вашего "внутреннего протокола"
        return string.Empty;
    }

    private byte[] ZipByte(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        GZipStream sw = new GZipStream(ms,
        CompressionMode.Compress);
        sw.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        sw.Close();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public delegate void CallBackFunction(IAsyncResult result);
public delegate string ParseRequest(string inputText);

public class WaitCallbacObject
{
    public HttpListenerContext Context { get; set; }
    public ParseRequest Parse { get; set; }
    public WaitCallbacObject() { }

}
```

Comment: Конечно интересно! Я пару раз на форумах натыкался на информацию что можно использовать HTTP, но до реализации как-то не доходило. И у меня сразу возник вопрос: будет использоваться же 80 порт? Работа браузера не будет как-то мешать передаче данных?

Comment: @Николай пожалуйста, почитайте про протокол TCP чтобы не задавать таких вопросов. Нет, браузер никак не помешает. А вот Skype славится тем, что любит "отжирать" себе 80й порт.